# Debugging CQRS Applications

Tags: debugging, cqrs

When debugging a CQRS dev env - do you bother developing with the esb running? Or do you fake the esb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on what you want to test.

If you want to test the whole chain, end-to-end (an integration test), then obviously the ESB is part of that chain.

If you want to debug command handlers or the service that receives the commands (unit tests), then the service bus is out of the picture.

For thorough testing, you need both. For quick testing, you only need the unit tests.